# Show another div if another is hidden

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

I have a div to show recently viewed items on a page which I am hiding if it's empty using innerHTML so the outer empty box doesn't show and it works fine.
The problem is that it leaves a great big hole on the page until an item has been viewed.

What I have been trying to do is show another div if div id="recentinc" is hidden which will in turn be hidden once div id="recentinc" has content.

Here is my code so far:

```
<div id="recentinc"><?php include 'recentview.php'; ?></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.getElementById('recentinc').innerHTML == '')
    document.getElementById('recently_viewed').style.display = 'none';
</script>
</div>
```

I would like to have another div eg.

```
<div id="copy">more content</div>
```

that will show instead when div id="recentinc" is hidden.

There may be a better way to do this with jQuery but I can't find an answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "great big hole"? If you do `display = 'none'` the element should not use up any space.

Comment: Why is this tagged as [tag:jquery]!? I think, you are clearly confusing [tag:javascript] and [tag:jquery]

Comment: @Alexander: He says he wasn't sure of a jQuery way. It does sound like he can distinguish between both - he is looking for a jQuery way if possible.

Comment: The div is in the left column underneath a menu. There is no content below it, so nothing to fill the space. When it does have content it fills all the space below the menu so when hidden there is empty space hence the reason for wanting to show another div in it's place. When the "recentview" div is shown there is no space below it to show any other content.

Comment: @Alexander: I was hoping that there may have been a neat jQuery way to do this hence the reason for the tag. I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to show/hide `#copy` based on the emptiness of `#recentinc`, and do the opposite for `#recently_viewed`.

```
var showRecent = $("#recentinc").children().length > 0;
$("#recently_viewed").toggle(showRecent);
$("#copy").toggle(!showRecent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the great big hole is, as setting the display to 'none' will remove the element from the flow. Try setting the visibilty instead of just hiding it with `display:none`, that way it will be invisible but still occupy the same space and still be in the document flow :

```
if (document.getElementById('recentinc').innerHTML == '')
    document.getElementById('recently_viewed').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

or jQuery:

```
$("#recently_viewed").css('visibility', $("#recentinc").is(":visible")?'hidden':'visible');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="recentinc"><?php include 'recentview.php'; ?></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($('#recentinc').html().length<1)
{
  $('#recently_viewed').hide();
}
</script>
</div>
```